# perform convolution operation in cuda

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, cuda, convolution, gpu-shared-memory

My code to perform the convolution operation (you check the operation in the provided link: https://prvnk10.medium.com/the-convolution-operation-48d72a382f5a) is working fine but failing some test cases.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

typedef long long ll;

#define TILE_SIZE 16
#define FILTER_SIZE 3

// CUDA kernel for convolution
// CUDA kernel for convolution
__global__ void convolutionKernel(long int* inputMatrix, long int* outputMatrix, long int* filter, int m, int n, int k) {
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ long int tile[TILE_SIZE + FILTER_SIZE - 1][TILE_SIZE + FILTER_SIZE - 1];

    // Load data into shared memory with padding
    int tileRow = threadIdx.y;
    int tileCol = threadIdx.x;

    int inputRow = row - FILTER_SIZE / 2;
    int inputCol = col - FILTER_SIZE / 2;

    if (inputRow >= 0 && inputRow < m && inputCol >= 0 && inputCol < n) {
        tile[tileRow][tileCol] = inputMatrix[inputRow * n + inputCol];
    } else {
        tile[tileRow][tileCol] = 0;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // Convolution computation using shared memory
    long int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            result += tile[tileRow + i][tileCol + j] * filter[i * k + j];
        }
    }

    // Write result to the output matrix
    if (row < m && col < n) {
        outputMatrix[row * n + col] = result;
    }
}


int main() {
    int m, n, k;
    cin >> m >> n >> k;

    long int* h_mat = new long int[m * n];
    long int* h_filter = new long int[k * k];
    long int* h_ans = new long int[m * n];

    for (long int i = 0; i < m * n; i++) {
        cin >> h_mat[i];
    }

    for (long int i = 0; i < k * k; i++) {
        cin >> h_filter[i];
    }

    // Allocate memory on the device (GPU)
    long int* d_mat, *d_filter, *d_ans;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_mat, m * n * sizeof(long int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_filter, k * k * sizeof(long int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ans, m * n * sizeof(long int));

    // Transfer data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_mat, h_mat, m * n * sizeof(long int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_filter, h_filter, k * k * sizeof(long int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Define grid and block dimensions
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);
    dim3 gridDim((n + blockDim.x - 1) / blockDim.x, (m + blockDim.y - 1) / blockDim.y);
    
    // Launch the CUDA kernel
    convolutionKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(d_mat, d_ans, d_filter, m, n, k);
    
    // Wait for the kernel to finish and check for errors
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t cudaError = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaError != cudaSuccess) {
        cerr << "CUDA error: " << cudaGetErrorString(cudaError) << endl;
    }

    // Transfer result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(h_ans, d_ans, m * n * sizeof(long int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout << h_ans[i * n + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(d_mat);
    cudaFree(d_filter);
    cudaFree(d_ans);

    // Free host memory
    delete[] h_mat;
    delete[] h_filter;
    delete[] h_ans;

    return 0;}
```

It is giving correct output for some test cases but wrong output for other test cases. Also it is taking very long to give output for very large inputs.

Comment: `FILTER_SIZE` is set a compile time, while `k` is set at runtime. Trying to run this code with any `k` that is not equal to `FILTER_SIZE` will certainly produce wrong output.

Comment: `inputRow` and `inputCol` should be calculated from `k` instead of `FILTER_SIZE`. Then you can either use dynamic shared memory or redefine `FILTER_SIZE` to be `MAX_FILTER_SIZE` (i.e. waste some shared memory for `k < MAX_FILTER_SIZE`).

Comment: Please use proper CUDA Runtime error checking, especially check `cudaGetLastError()` after launching a kernel. See [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/10107454) for how to do so in a non-intrusive but still informative manner.

Comment: @paleonix can you please provide the corrected code ??

Comment: If my comments are unclear I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: @paleonix I'm a beginner so your comments are a little confusing to me will it be alright for you to give the code with the changes that you have mentioned ?

Comment: `tile` has more elements than there are threads in your block, so some threads will have to fill more than one element. This could be achieved using another conditional or maybe using block-stride loops.